# OpenMP - Task dependency in Fortran

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am currently trying to use the *task* construct of OpenMP 4.0 including the *depend* statement for my Fortran codes. Therefore, I create the following example, which should fill up the first row of a matrix with the numbers 1 to M by a task and fill up the remaining elements by a task each whenever the element in the first row is ready. This results in the following piece of code:

```
PROGRAM OMP_TEST 
    IMPLICIT NONE 

    INTEGER K,L 
    INTEGER M
    PARAMETER (M = 8)
    INTEGER A(M,M) 

    A(1:M, 1:M) = 0

    !$omp parallel 
    !$omp single
    DO L=1, M 
        !$omp task depend(out:A(1,L)) default(shared) 
        A(1,L) = L
        !$omp end task 
        DO K = 2, M 
            !$omp task depend(in:A(1,L)) default(shared)
            A(K,L) = A(1,L) 
            !$omp end task
        END DO 
    END DO 
    !$omp taskwait 
    !$omp end single 
    !$omp end parallel

    DO K =1 , M 
        WRITE(*,*) A(K,1:M) 
    END DO 
END PROGRAM
```

Compile with the Intel Fortran 15 compiler, which is according to the documentation aware of the *depend* statement. But the result printed to the screen is different at every execution. Even the initial zeros of the matrix stay at some positions. For example:

```
       1           2           3           4           5           6
       7           8
       0           0           0           0           0           0
       0           0
       0           0           3           4           0           0
       0           8
       1           0           3           4           0           6
       0           8
       1           0           3           4           5           6
       0           8
       1           2           3           4           5           6
       7           8
       0           2           3           4           5           6
       7           0
       1           2           3           4           5           6
       0           8
```

Why does the dependencies between the task do not work correctly as I expect it such that the values 1 to 8 are in each row?

Comment: Compiling using gcc 5.4 produce a similar wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
!$omp task depend(in:A(1,L)) default(shared)
A(K,L) = A(1,L)
!$omp end task
```

considers `K` as shared, but at execution time of that task the value of `K` could have been modified elsewhere (in fact, that might only occur due to the thread executing the single - which is looping over `DO K = 2,M`). You can fix that by adding the `firstprivate` clause into the `!$omp` construct. This clause ensures that `K` will be private but also will inherit the value whenever that task is created.

This fact applies similarly to `L` in that very same statement as well as the task previous some lines before. The following code worked for me using Intel Fortran compiler version 16.0.

```
PROGRAM OMP_TEST
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER K,L
  INTEGER M
  PARAMETER (M = 8)
  INTEGER A(M,M)

  A(1:M, 1:M) = 0

  !$omp parallel
  !$omp single
  DO L=1, M
      !$omp task depend(out:A(1,L)) default(shared) firstprivate(L)
      A(1,L) = L
      !$omp end task
      DO K = 2, M
          !$omp task depend(in:A(1,L)) default(shared) firstprivate(K,L)
          A(K,L) = A(1,L)
          !$omp end task
      END DO
  END DO
  !$omp taskwait
  !$omp end single
  !$omp end parallel

  DO K =1 , M
      WRITE(*,*) A(K,1:M)
  END DO
END PROGRAM
```

**Update**

After exploring Grisu's comment where he/she refers to the Intel examples, I realized that the `K` and `L` should be already `firstprivate` since they are the loop variables in the `DO`. However, adding the `default(shared)` seems to change this behavior. The following code where the shared variables have been explicitly stated and `default` has been removed also works in Intel Fortran 16.0.

```
PROGRAM OMP_TEST
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER K,L
  INTEGER M
  PARAMETER (M = 8)
  INTEGER A(M,M)

  A(1:M, 1:M) = 0

  !$omp parallel
  !$omp single
  DO L=1, M
      !$omp task depend(out:A(1,L)) shared(A)
      A(1,L) = L
      !$omp end task
      DO K = 2, M
          !$omp task depend(in:A(1,L)) shared(A)
          A(K,L) = A(1,L)
         !$omp end task
      END DO
  END DO
  !$omp taskwait
  !$omp end single
  !$omp end parallel

  DO K =1 , M
      WRITE(*,*) A(K,1:M)
  END DO
END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Thanks that works, interestingly the examples on the Intel webpage does not rely on the firstprivate statement (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/581281) and many other examples not as well. But in this way it works and I can go on with my experiments.